# Why does server program freeze on line 'String file = br.readLine()'?

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to socket programming. I have to write a program where client accepts filename from a user and sends it to the server. The server reads corresponding file and sends its content back to client. Now my problem is server program freezes on 'String file = br.readLine()'. When I terminate my client program, further lines of server code get executed. If I comment out while loop at the end of my client code, server code works perfectly fine(it prints data to standard output). Can you tell what could be wrong with my code?
Server Code:

```
public class SocketServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Server is started.");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9999);

        System.out.println("Server is waiting for a client.");
        Socket server = ss.accept();

        System.out.println("Client is connected.");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        String file = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Requested file is: " + file);

        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(os);

        BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));   

        String line;
        while((line = fr.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.write(line);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
public class SocketClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 9999);

        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(os);

        System.out.print("Enter filename: ");
        String file = in.nextLine();

        writer.write(file);
        writer.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("Content of " + file + ":");

        String str;
        while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(str);
        }
        System.out.println("File transfer is complete.");
    }

}
```

Comment: You need a debugger.

Comment: I used a debugger. It showed me the line at which server program freezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`br.readLine();` will wait for input till it finds a new-line .

`writer.write(file);` You are writing file name without a new-line.

So in order to make it work either write a newline char at client or read it char by char at server.

Hope this helps.